# Unable to access Trash when running Nautilus with "sudo nautilus"

Tags: nautilus, trash

When trying to access the `Trash` area in Nautilus when running it from Terminal with the command:

```
sudo nautilus
```

I get this error:

[image: This location could not be displayed]

Is this because it is trying to access `trash:////` which is the not real path (the real path is `/home/<username>/.local/share/Trash`)? And if so is this some sort of bug, or is it somehow by design?

Comment: It's better to run "gksudo nautilus" instead of "sudo nautilus".

Comment: Please read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical%20sudo  (it explains @user300458 's comment and also your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user300458, you are mistaken my friend. The files you move to trash as sudo DO NOT get automatically deleted. It is a Nautilus bug as Paranoid Panda suspected. The trash can is not referenced properly here.

All files that were moved to trash can be found in: `/root/.local/share/Trash/files` - if you go there, you will find all the stuff you sent to trash intact and waiting for deletion.

I'm going to see if I can find a way to fix the reference for the trash on google.

In the meantime, you can empty it by browsing to `/root/.local/share/Trash/file` and opening the terminal and putting in:

```
rm -r *
```

There are also files in `/root/.local/share/Trash/info`. You can clean them out too if you care but those are small files.

**----------------------------------------------------------**
**[EDIT]** 
**----------------------------------------------------------**

I didn't find much but I kind of lost interest when I saw a post from 2008 with the same problem.

I just made a shell script:

```
rm -r -f -d /root/.local/share/Trash/files/*

rm -r -f -d /root/.local/share/Trash/info/*
```

And I left it in: `/root/.local/share/Trash`

Which I bookmarked in Nautilus. So, if I want to see the content of trash, I click on the files subdirectory and if I want to empty trash, I run the script.

Answer (score 2):

You ran Nautilus from the `root` account (`sudo`) and you're trying to access the Trash.

Normally, every user account has its own Trash, but `root` account doesn't have one. Because of elevated privileges, if you delete files while you're being `root` they'll be deleted immediately - no confirmations will be shown.

(Keep in mind that you should be **very careful** doing something as root!)

Comment: Root can have one, it just is different to the normal users

Comment: Root has definitely a trash folder: `/root/.local/share/Trash/`

Comment: im guessing nautilus searches for user's trash folder  in /home/username, but root doesn't have a folder in /home. But that's just a theory

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown -hR user:user ~/.local./share/Trash
```

You can now empty trash from Nautilus as a normal user, but not sure if permanently fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install trash-cli
```

Then:

```
sudo trash-empty
```

System should find it.

Comment: Is `sudo trash-empty` needed, or could we use `trash-empty` for local user?

Comment: trash-empty without sudo should empty current user trash only.

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu 19.04, I deleted some files as root on nautilus which I coudn't remove from Trash in nautilus. 
There was no `/root/.local/share/Trash` folder on my system, but there was `/home/<username>/.local/share/Trash/files`.
I simply `cd` to this directory and ran `sudo rm -rf *` and now there are no files in Trash as seen on nautilus.